# Antlr - How to generate exact input file to the output? (source-to-source transformation)

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr3, transpiler

Let's say I have a source code file. I want to give this file to the ANTLR and generate the same code and save it to an output file.

**Usage:**

1. To beautify the input file.
2. To add some comments to the input file.
3. To inject some code into the input file.

Is it possible to do such a thing by exploiting ANTLR?

Basically, I am trying to do a **source-to-source transformation with ANTLR**  from C/C++ to C/C++.

I am interested to add, delete, replace, or modify some lines of the code and generate an output that complies with C/C++ language rules.

---

P.S.: Please let me know if you know any other tool (other than CLANG) that does the same thing. Parsing C/C++ (or even Fortran) and providing some events to the user and let the user modify the source code.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. That's as useful answer as I can give to so broad question.

Comment: @JiriTousek oh. I thought I am seriously asking a very detailed question. How can I specialize it? It would be great if you let me know how to do it.

Comment: Well, ANTLR is a parser generator. If you need to create a parser, it is possible to use it, in general. Or you can use about any existing parser generator (as long as the class of grammars used is "strong enough" for your language). What exactly are your concerns, i.e. are there any specific things you expect ANTLR could have problems with?

Comment: Particularly, if the question is whether ANTLR produces the class of parsers that are able to parse C/C++ - yes it does, as evidenced by existing C and C++ grammars for ANTLR: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

Comment: @JiriTousek I am looking for this capability: while the parser is going through the parse tree and validates the source code (with the grammars as you mentioned), it emits the source code to the output too. Or, in other words, it emits the *symbols* to the output so that I can generate the input source code. With that feature, I also can emit other symbols as I am progressing on the parse tree.

Comment: However, based on what I am getting from the docs and examples, it seems like ANTLR only validates the language. It does not do any actions and it does not generate output files.

Comment: This is different in versions 3 and 4. Version 3 has an option to output AST (syntax tree) and can be used to keep track of all tokens on input (although you will need to take special care of whitespace tokens). I actually use it that way and am able to produce full original input. ANTLR 4 uses a different approach with listener or visitor to process the parsing result - but I'm not experienced with v4 so cannot give more info on that.